# how can i request from the api multiple times

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am having trouble calling the api multiple times

here's what i have done so far

```
let array = []; 

this.state.localjson.map((item) => {

  var floor = this.state.floor;
       var  date = this.formatDate(item.date);
       var  time = this.formatTime(item.time);
       var  id = item.id;
        item.date = this.formatDate(item.date);
        item.time = this.formatTime(item.time);

 axios.get(`http://localhost:3300/api/employees/${id}/${date}/${time}/${floor}`)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data === false) {
                    array.push(item);
                    this.setState({
                        result: array
                    });

                }


            })

        });
```

but the problem to this solution is that sometimes the api call failed due to simultaneous call

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Calling API in .map function and then even setting state on resolved promises is kind bad idea.

Comment: @zhuber i just need to call each item in this.state.localjson then check if it has a return or not.. sorry im still new at web development. do you know any alternative solutions?

Comment: Do you need to rerender after all have downloaded or after each successful request?

Comment: hmm because the response is async, thas why my set.state is inside of the response. but if you have a solution to that. feel free to share :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would go with something, that retries if there is a failure. It's easy to do with with tasks/async:

```
// Delay helper
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

this.state.localjson.forEach(async (item) => {
    let floor = this.state.floor;
    let  date = this.formatDate(item.date);
    let  time = this.formatTime(item.time);
    let  id   = item.id;
    item.date = this.formatDate(item.date);
    item.time = this.formatTime(item.time);

    let tries = 5;
    while (--tries >= 0) {
        try {
            var response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3300/api/employees/${id}/${date}/${time}/${floor}`);
            if (response.data === false) {
                this.setState({
                    result: this.state.result.concat(item)
                });
            }
            // Break out of the loop and return
            break;
        } catch (err) {
            // Await a delay (You can also use a backoff, like tries*1000 or an exponential backoff)
            // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff
            await delay(1000);
        }
    }
});
```

If we only want to cause one render after ALL the results have completed, you can use something like this:

```
// Delay helper
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

let finalResults = [];

await this.state.localjson.map((item) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let floor = this.state.floor;
    let  date = this.formatDate(item.date);
    let  time = this.formatTime(item.time);
    let  id   = item.id;
    item.date = this.formatDate(item.date);
    item.time = this.formatTime(item.time);
    let tries = 5;
    while (--tries >= 0) {
        try {
            var response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3300/api/employees/${id}/${date}/${time}/${floor}`);
            if (response.data === false) {
                finalResults.push(item);
            }
            //Resovle the promise, we're done here
            resolve();
            // Break out of the loop and return
            break;
        } catch (err) {
            // Await a delay (You can also use a backoff, like tries*1000 or an exponential backoff)
            // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff
            await delay(1000);
        }
    }

    // If we've reached this point, we've exhausted all of our errors
    reject();
}));


this.setState({
    results: finalResults
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause unnecessary re-renders and re-mapping since its calling setState() on each item?

Comment: I mean, if he wants to update as the results are coming in: (This could be a long call). If these are quick calls: I can provide an alternate solution.

Comment: it seems that it doesent work to me, and also the 2nd solution has an error? on await this.state.localjson.map((item)

Comment: When you use await syntax, the function must be marked as async. I encourage you to take a look as async/await in javascript @user3121362